# PHP connection incorrectly not detecting query update

Tags: php, mysql

Data updated or not, it shows *Sorry not updated*.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    include 'connection.php';
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $company = $_POST["company"];
    $model =  $_POST["model"];
    $price = $_POST["price"];
    $engno = $_POST["engno"];
    $query =  "UPDATE products SET company='".$company."', model='".$model."',`price`='".$price."', `engno`=$engno WHERE `id`=$id";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if($conn->query($result)===TRUE){
        echo  'Data Updated Successfully';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Sorry Not Updated';
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

}
?>
```

Comment: If you had error reporting enabled `$conn->query($result)===TRUE` would give an error.  `query()` would expect a SQL query string, but you are passing in the result of the previous call to `mysqli_query` which will be either true or false.

Comment: @Shahryar replace `$conn->query($result)===TRUE` with `if($result)`. You don't have to execute query again

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection. See about prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 1):

Check success status like below, `mysqli_query` will return `true`, you are trying to run query again `$conn->query($result)` where `$result` have either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
if($result){
    echo  'Data Updated Successfully';
}
```

For `mysqli_query`

> Return Value: For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, or EXPLAIN
>   queries it will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful
>   queries it will return TRUE. FALSE on failure

From [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

Comment: @NigelRen: Yes that's why I check `if($result){`